# How to get the type of encoding used in a X509 Subject field?

Tags: certificate, openssl, x509

In [RFC 5280](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5280.txt) is written that for example the `X520OrganizationName` can use one of the following encodings:

```
X520OrganizationName ::= CHOICE {
      teletexString     TeletexString
                          (SIZE (1..ub-organization-name)),
      printableString   PrintableString
                          (SIZE (1..ub-organization-name)),
      universalString   UniversalString
                          (SIZE (1..ub-organization-name)),
      utf8String        UTF8String
                          (SIZE (1..ub-organization-name)),
      bmpString         BMPString
                          (SIZE (1..ub-organization-name))  }
```

How can i lookup the used encoding in a given X509 certificate? Is there any openssl command or similar software?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use ASN.1 DER decoder software:

- OpenSSL: `openssl asn1parse -i -in Foo.crt`

  (asn1parse expects Base64 "PEM" format, as do most other openssl subcommands, but you can use `-inform DER` to give it binary-format certificates.)
- P.Gutmann's dumpasn1: `dumpasn1 Foo.der`

  (dumpasn1 requires the binary (non-Base64) format. Convert the certificate to binary DER using `openssl x509 -in Foo.crt -out Foo.der -outform DER` or even using `base64 -d`.)
- asn1.js (online): https://lapo.it/asn1js/

  (another similar version at https://pkitools.net/pages/ca/asn1.html)

Subject DN is one of the first fields in the certificate (<del>before</del> **after** the two timestamps – the Issuer DN is <del>after</del> before timestamps); it's represented as a 'Sequence' with each RDN being a 'Set' (typically having one element, but the format allows multiple, e.g. `CN=this+UID=that,OU=etc,O=etc`).

For example:

```
$ openssl x509 -outform DER -in Telia_Root_CA_v2.pem -out /tmp/telia.crt
$ dumpasn1 /tmp/telia.crt
  0 1396: SEQUENCE {
  4  860:   SEQUENCE {
  8    3:     [0] {                         ← Version (X.509 v3)
 10    1:       INTEGER 2
        :       }                           ↙ Serial number
 13   15:     INTEGER 01 67 5F 27 D6 FE 7A E3 E4 AC BE 09 5B 05 9E
 30   13:     SEQUENCE {                    ← Algorithm
 32    9:       OBJECT IDENTIFIER sha256WithRSAEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 11)
 43    0:       NULL
        :       }
 45   68:     SEQUENCE {                    ← Subject Issuer DN starts here
 47   11:       SET {
 49    9:         SEQUENCE {
 51    3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER countryName (2 5 4 6)
 56    2:           PrintableString 'FI'
        :           }
        :         }
 60   26:       SET {                       ← the 'O=...' RDN
 62   24:         SEQUENCE {                ← the 'O=...' element of the RDN
 64    3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER organizationName (2 5 4 0)
 69   17:           UTF8String 'Telia Finland Oyj'
        :           }
        :         }
 88   25:       SET {
 90   23:         SEQUENCE {
 92    3:           OBJECT IDENTIFIER commonName (2 5 4 3)
 97   16:           UTF8String 'Telia Root CA v2'
        :           }
        :         }
        :       }
115   30:     SEQUENCE {
117   13:       UTCTime 29/11/2018 11:55:54 GMT
```

Comment: _Issuer_ is the name before the validity (timestamps) and Subject is _after_. Your example is a root cert where they are the same so you can't tell the difference.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: That's a good point, thanks. Was writing it between work and somehow I didn't realize even though I was inspecting host certificates at first (which were too boring to use as examples whereas the Telia CA has mixed types).

Answer (score 1):

More specific and easier to read method with OpenSSL:

```
openssl x509 {<file | -in file} -noout -subject -nameopt oneline,show_type
# change -subject to -issuer (or use both!) if applicable 
# if DN is long or complex enough that single-line is hard to read 
# change oneline to multiline 

# for the cert currently used by www.example.com:

$ openssl x509 <temp -noout -subject # default does not show types
subject=C = US, ST = California, L = Los Angeles, O = Internet\C2\A0Corporation\C2\A0for\C2\A0Assigned\C2\A0Names\C2\A0and\C2\A0Numbers, CN = www.example.org

$ openssl x509 <temp -noout -subject -nameopt oneline,show_type
subject=C = PRINTABLESTRING:US, ST = PRINTABLESTRING:California, L = PRINTABLESTRING:Los Angeles, O = UTF8STRING:Internet\C2\A0Corporation\C2\A0for\C2\A0Assigned\C2\A0Names\C2\A0and\C2\A0Numbers, CN = PRINTABLESTRING:www.example.org

$ openssl x509 <temp -noout -subject -nameopt multiline,show_type
subject=
    countryName               = PRINTABLESTRING:US
    stateOrProvinceName       = PRINTABLESTRING:California
    localityName              = PRINTABLESTRING:Los Angeles
    organizationName          = UTF8STRING:Internet\A0Corporation\A0for\A0Assigned\A0Names\A0and\A0Numbers
    commonName                = PRINTABLESTRING:www.example.org
$
```

In older versions of OpenSSL the default format is PEM and you must specify `-inform DER` (or abbreviated `-inform d`) if it applies. However in 3.0.0 up, which are now the only versions supported upstream, *most* commands including `x509` accept input as either PEM or DER automatically. (`asn1parse` doesn't, because unlike other commands it doesn't look at or even require the PEM label lines; its 'PEM' format actually accepts *any* base64, unless you specify the new option `-strictpem`. Sometimes this is useful, sometimes not.)